# Add simple antispam operation in angularjs form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a input field like this :

```
                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                    <label for="antispam" class="col-sm-2 control-label">1+1+5 = ? 
    <span class="myForm_error" ng-show="myFormZR.antispam.$error.required">(required field)</span>
<span ng-show="myFormZR.antispam.$dirty && IsMatch">BAD ANSWER</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="antispam" placeholder="" required="required" ng-model="myForm.antispam" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

in ctrl :

```
/* antispam */
var antispamAnswer = "7"
if ($scope.myForm.antispam != antispamAnswer) {
    $scope.IsMatch = true;
} else {
    $scope.IsMatch = false;
}
```

It's not working, the mention "BAD ANSWER" is always show

Comment: can you brief what exactly you wanted to do?

Comment: i add test code but it's not working, the mention "BAD ANSWER" is always show

Comment: just add ng-show="myForm.antispam != 7"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs only once, when Controller is instantiated. You need put that code inside of $watch function for that ng-model:

```
$scope.$watch('myForm.antispam', function() {
  // that code
})
```

Also do lots of `console.log()` to debug your code, so you know what and when is happening in your application.